# I want to do a compareValue in rules for when a value has to be greater than one value AND less than another

Tags: yii2

I want to compare a value which needs to be greater than 8 or less than 3 and I can't seem to get it right. So far I can get it to show the error message if the value is less than 8.  My rule is

```
['taskmonth', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 8, 'operator' => '>', 'when'=> function($model){
            return $model->repeating_type == self::SIXMONTHLY;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) {
        return $('#repeating_type').val() = self::SIXMONTHLY;
        }", 'message' => 'The start month can only be September, October, November, December, January or February'],
```

this is a rule in my model. I get the correct error message when any month apart from Sept, Oct, Nov or Dec is selected but it should allow you to select Jan or Feb as well. I tried having 2 rules one with < 3 but I got an error message whichever month I tried to select then. I can't find anything in the docs to show having two compare values.  Can I do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for your case.

1) In case if it is crucial to use compare rule for this, you may activate it only if this values are in your restricted range.

```
[
    'taskmonth', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 3, 'operator' => '>',
    'when'=> function($model){ return $model->taskmonth >= 3 && $model->taskmonth <= 8 && $model->repeating_type == self::SIXMONTHLY; },
    'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) { return value >= 3 && value <= 8 && $('#repeating_type').val() == '". self::SIXMONTHLY. "'; }",
    'message' => 'The start month can only be September, October, November, December, January or February'
],
[
    'taskmonth', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 8, 'operator' => '<',
    'when'=> function($model){ return $model->taskmonth >= 3 && $model->taskmonth <= 8 && $model->repeating_type == self::SIXMONTHLY; },
    'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) { return value >= 3 && value <= 8 && $('#repeating_type').val() == '". self::SIXMONTHLY. "'; }",
    'message' => 'The start month can only be September, October, November, December, January or February'
]
```

2) You can work from other end. Run "in" rule, when you have self::SIXMONTHLY.
If you are sure in range of items there is available:

```
[
    'taskmonth', 'in','range'=>[1,2,9,10,11,12],
    'when'=> function($model){ return $model->repeating_type == self::SIXMONTHLY; },
    'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) { return $('#repeating_type').val() == '". self::SIXMONTHLY. "'; }",
    'message' => 'The start month can only be September, October, November, December, January or February'
]
```

3) Also in this case you may use match rule instead of in: 
`'taskmonth', 'match','pattern'=> '/^[^3-8]/', 'when' => ...`

P.S. Also a small note: `return $('#repeating_type').val() = self::SIXMONTHLY;` this is not comparing. This is applying. I think you meant `==`

Comment: fabulous, thanks for your help, I didn't see in range in the documentation, I've gone with that

Comment: @HelenPostle glad I could help. If this answer fits you, please mark question answered. Thanks.